# Implementation of short bubble and bubble sort

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, sorting, bubble-sort

[Bubble sort](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheBubbleSort.html)

In the above URL it is clearly written that short bubble is a modification in bubble sort to reduce the number of passes.
So in my implementation of both the algorithms i have added a counter which counts the number of passes and surprisingly both are having same no. of passes.
Here is my code:

```
def bubbleshort(mylist):
    flag= True
    passnum= len(mylist) -1
    counter = 0
    while flag and passnum > 0:
          flag = False

          for element in range(passnum):
                if mylist[element] > mylist[element + 1]:
                flag = True

                temp= mylist[element]
                mylist[element]= mylist[element+1]
                mylist[element + 1] = temp
                counter += 1
          passnum -= 1
    return mylist, counter

def bubble(yourlist):
    count=0
    for i in range(len(yourlist)-1, 0, -1):
        for swap in range(i):
            if yourlist[swap] > yourlist[swap + 1]:
                temp=yourlist[swap]
                yourlist[swap]=yourlist[swap + 1]
                yourlist[swap + 1]= temp
                count+= 1
    return yourlist, count

mylist = [20,30,40,90,50,60,70,80,100,110]
mylistx = [20,30,40,90,50,60,70,80,100,110]
sortedList, counter= bubbleshort(mylist)
sortList, count= bubble(mylistx)
print(sortedList,counter)
print(sortList,count)
```

Also if i pass same list to both the functions the the bubble function is producing zero counts but is still giving a sorted list.
So can anybody tell me what exactly is the purpose of modification when the no. of passes are same. Their maybe a chance that my implementation of counter is wrong that why i am getting wrong answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the input list whether the two functions go through the same number of passes.

For example, an almost sorted list like `[9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` takes only two passes for the short bubble function while it always takes 8 (`n-1`) passes for the regular bubble function.

Comment: But can you explain how does it works. I mean i have just added a flag

Comment: @Dr._Duck In each pass, we have a flag indicating whether there's any swap happening during the pass. If the flag says false, no further passes are needed and the list is already in sorted order.